# Pattern matching on atoms

Tags: elixir

I want to do a pattern matching over a command which return a tuple of (atom, var | atom)

```
  case run_command()
    {:ok, data} -> something1
    {:error, data} -> something2
  # {:error, :timeout} -> something3
  end
```

It throws an exception when `{:error, :timeout}` is returned. Why not `:timeout` is treated like a variable in pattern matching? How
can I match **any atom** in case of `{:error, data}`?

Comment: I think you should look into using the `_` underscore character.  Take a look at this documentation, http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @Chris, I'm aware of it.

Comment: `data` should match `:timeout`. Your third branch will never match if it's uncommented because `data` will match `:timeout`. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The exact code you've written should not throw an exception if `run_command()` returns `{:error, :timeout}`.

Comment: @Dogbert, I'll double check.

Comment: It might help to answer your question if you post _actual_ code rather than pseudo-code.